# How can I block bad row from a delete query

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a query that moves year-old rows from one table to an identical "archive" table.

Sometimes, invalid dates get entered in to a `dateprocessed` column (used to evaluate if the row is more than a year old), and the query errors out. I want to essentially "screen" the bad rows -- i.e. `where not isdate(dateprocessed)` does not equal 1 -- so that the query does not try to archive them.

I have a few ideas about how to do this, but want to do this in the absolute simplest way possible. If I select the good data into a temp table in my stored procedure, then inner join it with the live table, then run the delete from live output to archive -- will it delete from the underlying live table or the new joined table?

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks for the help. I am a .NET programmer playing DBA, but really want to do this properly.

Here is the query that errors when some of the `dateprocessed` column values are invalid:

```
delete from live 
output deleted.* into archive 
where isdate(dateprocessed) = 1 
  and cast (dateprocessed as datetime) < dateadd(year, -1, getdate()) 
  and not exists (select * from archive where live.id = archive.id)
```

Comment: why not fix your design and use a datetime field to begin with, there whould be no invalid dates stored in a datetime field.

Comment: You need 4 steps: Copy, Process, Archive, Delete

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is:

- Select the correct records into a temp table
- One of the fields you need to copy into the temp table should be a
  unique identifier like an "ID" column
- Do any additional processing in the temp table
- Archive from the temp table to archive table
- Delete from live table with a join with temp table using the "ID" Column. This will ensure no mistakes are made.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a .NET guy you could bring every data down and do a DateTime.TryParse.   Better yet just do it once to populate a real DateTime column.   The the dates that don't parse you could assign a fixed date or null.   And there are some dates strings that .NET will parse that SQL will not (.e.g. November 2010).